# backing up software installed from repository

Tags: apt, backup, repository

I have installed kubuntu-desktop from the ubuntu reposiitory. It seems to have messed up my unity GUI. SO i want to uninstall it,but I want to create a backup of the app before I remove, because I do want to try it out later on , and I have very low bandwidth so I dont want to download it again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Answer (score 0):

You would not need to download it again since packages you download get cached on your local drive and when you install again it won't download but use existing files. These are located at `/var/cache/apt/archives` if I'm not mistaken.

You can do a backup of your system and recover from it afterwards if you'd like. Check this out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem